# Embedded admin template

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, sonata, symfony-sonata

I'd like to drastically customise the layout for one particular embedded admin. My block sits like so:

```
->add('options', CollectionType::class, [
    'by_reference' => false,
    'label' => false,
], [
    'edit' => 'inline',
   'inline' => 'table',
])
```

On the admin block within the `.yaml` I've tried adding a calls then set template and I've had no luck.

I've also tried:

```
[
    'edit' => 'inline',
    'inline' => 'table',
    'template' => 'admin/example/example.html.twig'
]
```

Finally, I also tried within my `OptionAdmin` using the method `setFormTheme()`.

Any help or suggestions would be much appreciated.